# Can NHibernate persist to flat files instead of database?

Tags: database, nhibernate, persistence, flat-file

Here is a curiousity question.  I have an application that must support both flat files and the database as a place to persist data.  I was thinking maybe using a .csv or tab-delimited set of files as input ...

Is it possible to use NHibernate to write to do both persistance tasks?

Comment: Do the files have to be human readable or is the requirement just to be able to push out to a file as opposed to monolithic db? If human readable isn't necessary i'd suggest SqlLite which NHibernate does support IIRC.

Comment: +1 to Quarrelsome. I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Jet engine (see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2003/10/01/29964.aspx))

Dialect and other nhibernate settings should be the ones [for Microsoft Access](http://www.hibernate.org/361.html#A4).

Answer (score 2):

No not to the best of my knowledge. I have the same requirement and have ended up just using flat XML files and hand rolling all the CRUD.

Just today I did happen to notice this [File System Database](http://filesystemdatabase.codeplex.com/) on codeplex but haven't looked into it properly yet.